Does the flavor enhancer E635 (Disodium Ribonucleotides) Require a Hechsher?
I've seen a few places saying it's kosher like this:
https://www.foodsweeteners.com/kosher-certified-disodium-5-ribonucleotides/
However on the isitkosher app it's listed as not kosher:
https://isitkosherapp.com/e-additives
Which is strange, because I've seen it in certified kosher products (CoR).
So, does it require a Hechsher?

The first website looks like one of those computer generated aggregator websites. I wouldn't trust anything on it.

Here's a good guide: https://www.kosher.org.uk/Enumbers

@Kazibácsi That's a list of what is problematic. It doesn't include this number, so would that definitively tell you that E635 is kosher? Whether it requires hechsher?

This is exactly why you should ask an expert rabbi about it!

There seems to be conflicting information available as to whether or not one of the components of E635 is animal-derived. It would seem that, if it was animal derived, it would require a hechsher, although it might all be vegetable-derived these days. You would need to speak with someone knowledgeable in the industry to know for sure.
